# Route problem on production after build vue application

Tags: apache, vue.js, vue-router, production, building

So, I'm building an application with Vuejs and after we finish her we decided to finally build for production. Everything worked just fine while building and etc, but when the application was really being hosted, we noticed some issues that we do not saw while on localhost (development and production).

I'm saying this after a lot of tests and researches about it because first, I thought that the problem was after building to production but we tested another way to host and it's not apache that is causing this issue and I really think that is not the code either. Anyway the problem is when we first access the application our login page is the first that you can see and it works just fine at the first access but if the user refreshes the page for any reason the page loses all her CSS because the route /auth/login goes to /auth/login/ and after some tests I can confirm. That bar that is added at the end of the route makes the page lose CSS.

This problem we solved by adding an exception on our .htaccess (we know that this is not that best practice but anyway) after this solved we saw another problem: when we click on a link for example /auth/login?token=12334567890 the token param simply disappear and the user is automatically redirected to /auth/login. So we think that maybe these two problems are related because when we first access and log in everything inside the application works as it should, these two problems are only occurring on our login component. My question is what is causing this problem only on this page? It's a vue-router that is causing?

Comment: I once lost the styles on refresh and the issue was, that I has non-scoped CSS in the Login component, which I then reused in the Registration component. Usually, I went from the Login to the Registration, so it made no difference. But when I went directly to the Registration page, the page was unstyled.

Comment: Your problem though seems like there is a path issue (when `/` is added to the path, and the styles cannot be loaded anymore, it sounds like you are using a relative path). Does your server support history mode? What happens if you disable history mode and try it with the anchor (`#`)?